# Get OpenGL LookAt Position

Tags: android, opengl-es, matrix

In Android OpenGL

it has the command setLookAtM to specific the position for the camera view

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY,
            lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);
```

If I rotate camera, by using command rotateM

```
Matrix.rotateM(mViewMatrix, 0 , angle , 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Then, How could I get the **'LookAt'** the exact camera view from mViewMatrix ?

the camera view position, i want is x,y,z that camera look at

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finished my question 
and this is my solution

first, I need to made this 3 matrix to get result of x, y, z position

```
private float[] mRotXMatrix = new float[] {
 1, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 1, 0,
 0, 1, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 1 };
private float[] mRotYMatrix = new float[] {
 0, 0, 1, 0,
 0, 1, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 1 };
private float[] mRotZMatrix = new float[] { 
 0, 1, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 1, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 1 };
```

Then in onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) method I rotate all these 3 matrix together with my camera view like this

```
Matrix.multiplyMM(mViewMatrix, 0, deltaRotationMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mRotXMatrix, 0, deltaRotationMatrix, 0, mRotXMatrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mRotYMatrix, 0, deltaRotationMatrix, 0, mRotYMatrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mRotZMatrix, 0, deltaRotationMatrix, 0, mRotZMatrix, 0);
```

And to get the X, Y, Z of my camera view, just get it from these matrix

```
viewX = mRotXMatrix[2];
viewY = -mRotYMatrix[6]; // +/- up to your initial camera view
viewZ = mRotZMatrix[10];
```

Comment: What is the deltaRotationMatrix and why would mRotXMatrix be different to mRotYMatrix and so on if you apply the same multiplyMM

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, as calling rotateM doesn't technically rotate the camera, it applies a rotation to any future objects drawn. (it doesn't mean the same thing).

However in general, if you have a view matrix, and you want to see which direction it is facing, you want to transform the eye space forward vector (0,0,1) by the inverse of the view matrix.

As the view matrix transforms vectors in world space into eye space, the inverse view matrix transforms vectors from eye space into world space.

So you can:

1. Apply arbitrary operations to the current view matrix
2. Take its inverse
3. Multiply the inverse matrix by (0,0,1,0). (note this is the same as just pulling out the third column of the inverse matrix).

After #3 you will have the direction of the camera eye in world space. Add this to the eye's position, and you should know at what point it is pointing.

Comment: Really thanks for reply, Tim

However, the 3 value from third column is just the **rotation value** that represent the degree of the gyro sensor.. not the exact position x,y,z

I know that this value could lead to the result but i can't figure out how to convert this 3 values to get the exact position